# "тонкая синхронизация" в односвязном списке

Tags: c, многопоточность, синхронизация

Добрый день!
Недавно подсмотрела в курсах интересный вариант работы со списками в многопоточной среде, обозвали эту модель там "тонкой синхронизацией". Суть состоит в том, что во время работы со списком блокируется доступ только к текущему и предыдущему элементу списка при любых операциях типа удаления/вставки, и при этом коллизий не возникает. Кто-нибудь использовал этот способ синхронизации на реальных задачах?
Вот приведенный в курсах пример добавления элемента к связному списку на псевдокоде :

```
  Node prev = head; prev.lock();
  Node curr = prev.next; curr.lock();

  try{
    while(curr.key < key){
    prev.unlock(); prev = curr;
    curr = curr.next; curr.lock();
    }
    if(key == curr.key) return false;
    else{
      node = new Node(key,item);
      node.next = curr;
      pred.next = node;
      return true;
    }
  } finally{curr.unlock();pred.unlock();}
```

Если переложить этот пример на С, то я должна создать список, элементами которого будут экземпляры некой структуры, содержащей мьютекс. Вот на этом месте у меня возникает вопрос, как реализовать хотя бы первую строку данного кода без риска поймать segfault в случае, когда:

1. первый поток получил указатель на головной элемент списка,
2. управление получил второй поток, и удалил головной элемент списка,
3. управление вернулось к первому потоку, он пытается захватить мьютекс головного элемента списка, которого уже нет в живых...
   ?

Comment: Ага, верно подмечено. Я вот тоже на первой строке подвис, недочитав вопрос.

Comment: @margosh, а ведь нигде не сказано, что этот код **должен** работать при удалении элементов. 

Вероятно для реализации удаления нужна еще пара Ваших любимых (кстати, как они поживают) pthread_rwlock_wrlock/pthread_rwlock_rdlock. Поток вставки (тот что сейчас рассматриваем) должен сделать pthread_rwlock_rdlock перед первым prev.lock();

--

Реально здесь вопрос в другом. Все такие локи это дорогие операции и IMHO просто сожрут все время. Быстрее будет последовательно.

Comment: Наверняка использовали авторы идеи.

Я бы просто обернул все операции с этим списком в критическую секцию и не собирал на г.. сметану

Comment: @avp, смысл всей этой синхронизации был как раз в том, чтобы безопасно редактировать(т.е. и добавлять и удалять) спискок без использования каких-либо блокировок на весь список. Идея была в том, что так как захватывается всегда не менее 2-х мьютексов(текущего и предыдущего элемента) - список всегда будет в консистентном виде, тогда можно было бы одновременно удалять его элементы например из середины и конца списка.

Comment: @margosh, я понимаю этот алгоритм. Если учесть ответ @VladD (голова не меняется и список кроме нее содержит хотя бы один элемент), то код работать будет. Допустим, мы обращаемся к этому коду, только проверив указанные условия.

--

Другой вопрос насколько эффективно. Попробуйте простой тест на массиве из миллиона элементов и миллионе инкрементов случайно выбранного элемента (в каждом есть мьютекс) и 2-х потоков.

И сравните с одним потоком и 2 млн. инкрементов.

Comment: @avp: на самом деле, использовать coarse-grained lock vs. fine-grained lock, зависит от паттерна использования. Если у нас, например, есть много длинных операций, во время которых _один_ элемент списка должен быть заблокирован, fine-grained lock может быть лучше.

---
Обратите внимание на недостаток обсуждаемого алгоритма: он запрещает проход по списку _через_ обрабатываемый элемент, так что длинная обработка недалеко от головы списка эффективно блокирует почти все новые операции со списком.

Comment: @avp, естественно этот алгоритм не под все задачи годится. к моим блокировкам чтения-записи он отношения не имеет - это уже другая задача

Comment: @VladD, IMHO про *обработку элемента* здесь вообще речь не идет. Речь об изменении контейнера.

А Ваш комментарий это, видимо, по поводу провести указанный тест? Суть там это обход (посещение), а не изменение. Хотел предложить именно простой в реализации тест, а так можно и на этих же списках проверить (если не лень), что однопоточный алгоритм будет быстрее на порядок.

Comment: @avp: Если речь идёт лишь об изменении контейнера, мне сложно с лёту придумать пример, на котором fine-grained locking будет иметь неоспоримое преимущество. Держать блокировку на время обработки _иногда_ имеет смысл: чтобы исключить возможность одновременной параллельной обработки элемента, и уже тем более удаление обрабатываемого элемента из другого потока. (Более правильно было бы наверное самому удалить элемент из списка на время обработки, а потом при необходимости вставить заново?)

Comment: @avp: вы имеете в виду, отдельная блокировка на структуру, и отдельная -- на данные? Здравая мысль, кстати, заодно решает проблему с проходом "сквозь" обрабатываемый элемент. (Только для удаления надо брать _обе_ блокировки тогда.)

Comment: пришлось удалить-вставить (последний комментарий, редактировать не дает) поэтому не по месту.

--

@VladD, для блокировки обработки элемента IMHO лучше добавить свой мьютекс (блокировка данных) и брать его через trylock.

--

@VladD,

    (Только для удаления надо брать обе блокировки тогда.)

Это зависит об общего алгоритма обработки. Если удаление это только remove из списка, то можно сделать независимо. Только надо, например обнулить `next`, чтобы поток после обработки не пошел дальше. А так ничего страшного.

Comment: @avp: я имел в виду алгоритм, который считает, что пока данные заблокированы, он имеет право их читать и записывать. В этом случае, если кто-то хочет удалить элемент, он обязан убедиться, что ни у кого нету блокировки на чтение данных -- то есть фактически взять самому эту блокировку.

---
Хотя может быть тут нужен rwlock :-) r = доступ к данным (на чтение или запись), w = модификация структуры.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, этот код исходит из того, что голова списка фиктивна и неизменна. Это часто используемая техника, позволяющая не выделять специальный случай пустого списка.

В таких предположениях код, кажется, верен.

Инвариант алгоритма таков: для работы с элементом необходима блокировка как самого Node, так и его предшественника. Если у вас есть блокировка на Node или на его предшественника, ваш Node гарантированно жив.

Я бы, однако, не стал использовать обработку исключений для анализа достижения конца списка (тем более, что в данном коде не проверяется `head.next`), и оставил исключения для исключительных ситуаций.

Comment: т.е. head - "пограничный" элемент, иными словами.

Comment: Со второй строкой всё в порядке: покуда у нас есть lock на head, элемент head.next гарантированно жив.

Comment: @mega: почему? `prev` -- просто указатель на предшествующий текущему элементу.

Comment: >покуда у нас есть lock на head, элемент head.next гарантированно жив.

Скорее всего, он гарантированно не меняется, а не жив :) Видимо, предполагается, что список непустой.

Comment: @VladD, Вы правы - тут вся загвоздка именно в предположении, что голова фиктивна и ее никто не удаляет. Спасибо!

Comment: @mega: не только не меняется, но и жив. Потому что для того, чтобы его удалить, надо предварительно получить на него lock.

Comment: @margosh: Гарантии есть. Посмотрите внимательнее инвариант. Для того, чтобы элемент умер, другому потоку надо захватить блокировку и на этот, и на предыдущий элемент. А в тот момент, когда мы получали указатель на текущий элемент, предыдущий элемент был нами заблокирован.

Comment: @margosh: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @mega: вы правы, код не проверяет указатели на null. Код внутри try/catch вылетит в catch (хотя это не самый лучший стиль, проверка неисключительных условий при помощи исключений не комильфо), а вот если head.next == null, будут проблемы.